# GWT: does code-splitting have any effect when in development mode

Tags: gwt, gxt

I've read in so many places that code-splitting can significantly speed up the initial loading time of a GWT application.
However, before we do the splitting, we would like to know whether the deferred download of codes also work when in development mode?

Currently our most painful point is that in development mode with debug mode, when we refresh the browser (to refresh the changes in client code) it will take 3.7 years for the app to reload.
In production mode the application will load in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code splitting has absolutely no effect in Dev Mode, because your application is not compiled to JavaScript.

When GWT.isScript() is false (Dev Mode) RunAsyncCallback.onSuccess() method is run immediately. It is apparent if you inspect the source code of the GWT.runAsync() method.

EDIT: just a small thing to add as well: do NOT use Chrome with DevMode. Chrome still has an outstanding bug (the link escapes me right now) that makes the DevMode Plugin for Chrome run really slowly. Use Firefox, it is the fastest with the Dev Mode plugin.

Answer (score 4):

As said before code splitting has absolutely no effect in Dev Mode. 
Only thing that I could suggest you is to increase memory for jvm on start: 
For example we use in our project:

```
-Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Also upgrade your working hardware(CPU, memory), it's could help you to compile faster your java code on Dev mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you want faster DevMode you should be more careful with how you write your application. User lazy loading where possible, split app into standalone modules.
E.g. let's say you have some app with 5000 classes.  And usually a developer needs to change only some part of application, not all application (one page for example). So basically you need to make sure that to start one simple part of app, only classes needed by the app are loaded. E.g. instead of loading 5000 classes only 100 will be loaded. Also check for common errors like RPC Type Explosion, they affect devmode as well. And try GWT 2.4 it is much faster than previous versions (I mean DevMode).

Answer (score 0):

In my (medium length) experience I noticed Internet Explorer 9 is also pretty fast in Dev Mode, and a lot more stable than Chrome. The GWT plug-in doesn't crash every other reload of the application.

You could give it a try, see if it works better for you.